# CQRS can query be source of event?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Usually when talk implementing CQRS it is supposed that commands are sorces for events. But can queries made by user be source of created events in event store? Or such actions (when we need an event that reflects query) should be implemented using command still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can queries made by user be source of created events in event store?

*Go not to the elves for counsel, for they will answer both no and yes.*

So, the "no" part: queries are distinguished by the fact that they don't change the domain model.  In a CQRS implementation, the queries are being served by the read model, which may not even have access to your event store at all.

> when we need an event that reflects query

The yes part: there's no law that says you can't assemble a history of queries, and stick that in your event store.

But I'm stumped, in that I don't see a clear case where the *domain* needs an event that reflects a query.  That's really weird.  My guess would be that needing an event that reflects a query is a hint that your model is broken.

You may be able to make some progress with this by exploring the source of the requirement.

If the requirement is coming from operations, analytics, reporting, usability... then the domain model probably isn't the right place for that information.

If the requirement is coming from your domain experts ("we need to capture these queries so that the model supports the right changes later"), then you should be looking to identify what entity is responsible for tracking that the query happened, and sending an appropriate command to that entity.

Comment: For example if need to fixate if user pressed some button in the application and saw some data in opened form (a query will be called to get the data), should I have a domain command for this?